# Filter dataframe based on groupby sum()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I want to filter my dataframe based on a groupby sum().  I am looking for lines where the amounts for a spesific date, gets to zero.

I have solve this by creating a for loop.  I suspect this will reduce performance if the dataframe is large.

It also seems clunky.

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
newdf['name'] = ('leon','eurika','monica','wian')
newdf['surname'] = ('swart','swart','swart','swart')
newdf['birthdate'] = ('14051981','198001','20081012','20100621')
newdf['tdate'] = ('13/05/2015','14/05/2015','15/05/2015', '13/05/2015')
newdf['tamount'] = (100.10, 111.11, 123.45, -100.10)

df = newdf.groupby(['tdate'])[['tamount']].sum().reset_index()
df2 = df.loc[df["tamount"] == 0, "tdate"]
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df2:
    df3 = df3.append(newdf.loc[newdf["tdate"] == i])

print (df3)
```

The below code is creating an output of the two lines getting to zero when combined on tamount

```
   name surname  birthdate       tdate  tamount
0  leon   swart 1981-05-14  13/05/2015    100.1
3  wian   swart 2010-06-21  13/05/2015   -100.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use basic numpy :)

```py
import numpy as np

df = newdf.groupby(['tdate'])[['tamount']].sum().reset_index()

dates = df['tdate'][np.where(df['tamount'] == 0)[0]]

newdf[np.isin(newdf['tdate'], dates) == True]
```

Hope this helps; let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a lot cleaner and works like a charm

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.